# Invalid syntax string comparison python wiki parser

Tags: python

So using python 2.7 now after reverting back from 3.3.4

I'm using

```
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

article = sys.argv[1]
articleURL = urllib.quote(article)
print article
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

MAX_HOPS = 100
count=1

While article!="Philosophy" and count<MAX_HOPS:
    resource = opener.open("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + articleURL)
    data = resource.read()
    resource.close()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    print soup.find('div',id="bodyContent").p
    count+=1
```

for while article!="Philosophy" I am getting a Invalid Syntax Error pointing to article. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong

Comment: `While` != `while`. The latter is a Python loop command. The former is undefined, hence the syntax error...

Answer (score 1):

If your code snippet is the exact code you're executing, it will produce the following exception:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    While article!="Philosophy" and count<MAX_HOPS:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The problem is the capital `W` in the line `While article!="Philosophy" and count<MAX_HOPS:` even though the traceback is pointing to article.

The solution is simple. Use a `while` instead of `While`.

Regarding Python `SyntaxError`s, sometimes the traceback isn't perfect. If the output is a bit confusing, look a bit before the line/section indicated.

Answer (score 0):

It is `while`, not `While` (that is, lowercase w). The interpreter thinks `While` is a name and it tries to parse an assignment or an expression, and it fails at `article`.